# Return smallest unique value that meets criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to return the smallest unique value that meets a specific criteria, to the Nth term. Please look at image:

[image: Example Layout]

Goal is to have a formula in cells D2:G31 that will return the values of B2:B31 in order of smallest to largest that contain the value in D1:G1.

For example cell D2 would return 3 because it is the smallest value in the "1's" group. Cell D3 would return 12, Cell E2 would return 1, Etc...

I have tried using the code below but it just returns TRUE, I am not sure how to achieve my goal, but maybe this will help your understanding.

```
=AND(VLOOKUP(1,A2:B31,2),SMALL(B2:B31,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) function provides a great method of solving this type of problem without needing array formulas. I mocked up a similar problem and used the following formula in cell `E2` (dragging across and down)

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$12/($A$1:$A$12=E$1),ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

See [this answer from Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084442/2859347) for a better explanation of how it works and also an example with multiple criteria.

Comment: I am having an issue understanding this function. I have tried the following with no luck.

Comment: `=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$31,1,$A$2:$A$31=$E$1)`

Comment: @KevinP. Try this instead `=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$31/($A$2:$A$31=E$1),ROW(1:1))`

Comment: Works great! Thank you! I think I understand what it happening now.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) should work for you.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$31=D$1,$B$2:$B$31,""),ROW()-ROW(D$1)),"")
```

Comment: I spoke too soon, this worked great for my example but for some reason when I transition it over to my real application it is leaving out some numbers. No apparent relationships but it only fulfilled 10 of 14 numbers in my first row, and 2 of 6 in my second. Odd.

Comment: Make sure you have the formula entered with `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`.

Comment: I do, I am trying to understand the last part of your code to troubleshoot this. It is mathematically subtracting the value I am looking for from the calculated value?

Comment: Since you want to return the value from the smallest, The 2nd parameter for `SMALL` function is the indicator of which small value you want to return.  The first small number will be 1 and the second one will be 2 and so on.  `ROW()-ROW(D$1)` is the math to return 1, 2, 3 etc so that `SMALL` function knows which one you want to return based on the positions of the row.  `ROW()` is basically pointing to the current row, and `ROW(D$1)` is 1 in this example.  So on row 5 you will have (5 - 1) = 4 which will return 4th small value.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense and that's where my problem lies. In my actual application I am starting at B13 through G62 and the source (where the 1 is) is in B$9.

Comment: I think I have it configured right now, I used ROW()-ROW(C$12). Sorry I got so lost with that, seems I overthought it. Thank you!

Comment: Good that you know how this works and it will help you down the road.