# How to return row value that meets two criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have an excel spreadsheet to keep track of project activities.

In Column A I have the Project Name and it repeats several times because the same project has several activities.

In Column B I have the Activities related to that project.

In Column C I have the % Complete of each activity.

What I would like to accomplish is: in Column D return the **first** Activity of the Project that is not 100%.

Here is a picture of what I would like to accomplish:

[image: Expected Result]

I was trying this formula with no luck:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$19,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($C$2:$C$19<>100%,),0))
```

Then I found this one posted here:

> [Return smallest unique value that meets criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654376/return-smallest-unique-value-that-meets-criteria)

and here:

> [multiple criteria small function excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083611/multiple-criteria-small-function-excel/39084442#39084442)

But I haven't been able to get them to do what I want.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, here is a slightly more accurate formula than @AlexisOlson's:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$19,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$19=A2)*($C$1:$C$19<>1),0))
```

Typically, it is not a good idea to have concatenations within `MATCH` because it may lead to incorrect results.

For example:

```
= MATCH("12"&"34",{"1","12"}&{"234","34"},0)
```

This formula would return 1 when you would actually want it to return 2.

Changing to this:

```
= MATCH(1,({"1","12"}="12")*({"234","34"}="34"),0)
```

Will remove any risk of falsely picking the wrong lookup values.

Of course, in this particular case, it makes no difference, because there is no possible way that `$C$1:$C$19<>1` could return anything other than `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but it is just something to be aware of.

The only time I will use the `&` approach inside `MATCH` is if I actually desire to find the concatenation of strings in a single range, e.g. something like:

```
= MATCH("John"&" "&"Doe",{"John Doe","Bill Miller","Mike Jones"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to match on two conditions, the Project and the percent:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$19, MATCH(A2&TRUE, $A$1:$A$19&($C$1:$C$19 <> 1), 0))
```

This needs to be entered as an array formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter in the formula box.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Alexis. It worked just perfect! So, if I want to add a third condition (a third column, for example) I should add it inside the MATCH, right?

Comment: Interesting approach. Instead of `MATCH(A2&TRUE, $A$1:$A$19&($C$1:$C$19 <> 1), 0)`, I would have done `MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$19=A2)*($C$1:$C$19<>1),0)`. In this case it makes no difference but in general I avoid using concatenation inside `MATCH` because it may lead to incorrect results. For example `MATCH("12"&"34",{"1","12"}&{"234","34"},0)` would return 1 when actually you are looking for 2. In this case it makes no difference but just something to be aware of. Still +1.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 That's a good point. I'd suggest turning your comment into another answer as well.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Ok, I have added an answer.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Sorry, didn't intend to steal the accepted answer from you, just wanted to give clarification.