# How to count number of occurences

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

How can I write formula that counts how many John and James are in my column that are from USA. The answer for this example will be 2 (John-USA and James-USA)

Please note that this example is simple. I may have 100000 rows and 1000 names.

Comment: You can use 2 COUNTIFS, 1 for John-USA and 1 for James-Usa, and sum them up

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pivot table, though `countifs` can handle the specific case.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to refer to a list of names you want to include as some sort of `OR` operator:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A6,C1:C2,B1:B6,"USA"))
```

> ***Note:*** Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `SUMPRODUCT` will help:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6&B1:B6="JohnUSA")+(A1:A6&B1:B6="JamesUSA"))
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to count 50 names? I can't write 50 +'s

Comment: Please be very careful concatenating ranges. It's something I would highly recommend to avoid. What if someone is called `LUU` from South Africa `SA`. Would the concatenated value be "LUUSA" as Lu from the USA or Luu from SA (maybe a terrible example namewise, but you get the idea :) )

Comment: That's a very fair point! Didn't think about that. Thanks @JvdV I guess I would need to introduce some sort of delimiter to take care of it.

Comment: @JustynaMK A delimiter won't necessarily work in all cases. The only sure safe way is to treat them as separate entries. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811811/how-to-return-row-value-that-meets-two-criteria-in-excel) is another question where one of the answers uses concatenation instead of treating the values separately. It could also be an issue with `MATCH`, not just `SUMPRODUCT`. Again most times it makes no difference, but it is something you should be aware of. Still a good answer, I upvoted.

Comment: Many thanks @ImaginaryHuman072889, that's another useful lesson for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way would be using COUNTIFS:

> **[COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**

[image]

The formula I've used in `D2`is:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6;"John";$B$1:$B$6;"USA")+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6;"James";$B$1:$B$6;"USA")
```

**UPDATE:** If you need to count several names at once from several countries, use a Pivot Table:

I did a dataset like this (note I added headers):

[image]

Create a Pivot Table based on data:

1. Take NAME and COUNTRY to FILTERS section
2. Take NAME again, but into VALUES section, and make sure the operation is COUNT

Playing with the filters you can choose 1 or more countries (or even all) and also 1 or more names (or even all) and the Pivot Table will calculate the result.

[image]

After applying filters `COUNTRY=USA` and `NAME=John OR JAMES` I get as result 2:

[image]

Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: What if I want to count 50 names? I can't write 50 +'s

Answer (score 2):

Based on your common complaint "*What if I want to count 50 names? I can't write 50 +'s*", you must specify **somewhere** the list of names to count (whether hardcoded in the formula [in that case you will need 50 +'s], or in a list somewhere in your workbook). Otherwise, how can your formula magically know which 50 names to look for?

My suggestion is to make a separate list, count the entries for each item in the individual list, then sum them all up at the end.

For example:

[image]

Also possible to perform the sum of the counts all at once:

For example:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2:D3,B:B,E2:E3))
```